# In ember app chrome beta version - Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

In chrome beta version I got the below error in one of my app,

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for
>   resource
>   'http://localhost:8000/assets/vendor-2d2d91b98d3771c414a0b039e0b4d8c1.js'
>   with computed SHA-256 integrity
>   'RtMfPvtdjkEbERLgZ70Z5f8rCHbsou/DcqEZCXiM8ME='. The resource has been
>   blocked.

As [github thread](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/5040) pointed out that its fixed but I am getting this error in `ember-cli-2.14.1` and `"ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",` so I am going to include `integrity=''`. I would like to know , is there any consequences for this change?

Comment: In your linked thread, someone mentions seeing this error message in the production build and someone else points out that [that is probably a different issue](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/5040#issuecomment-230599490).

I am seeing this problem now with ember-cli 2.18.2 and (non-beta) Chrome 66 (possibly since 65) and only when reloading my app after deploying a new version - it goes away after clearing the browser cache, but I would like to know the root cause, too.

Answer (score 6):

the script or css you draw in(maybe in CDN) has changed.But your html used integrity to ensure the file not changed. for example:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-xBuQ/xzmlsLoJpyjoggmTEz8OWUFM0/RC5BsqQBDX2v5cMvDHcMakNTNrHIW2I5f" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```